# Prove complex satisfying $|z+a\bar{z}|=r$ is ellipse

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove complex numbers satisfying $|z+a\bar{z}|=r$ are ellipse. Here $0<|a|<1$, $r>0$.
I don't know how to address this problem in an easy way.
Polar coordinate doesn't make the problem easier.
Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$z=x+iy,\quad \bar{z}=x-iy$$ then
$$z+a\bar{z}=(x+iy)+a(x-iy)=(1+a)x+i(1-a)y$$
and remembering that $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, we get that
$$|z+a\bar{z}|=\sqrt{(1+a)^2x^2+(1-a)^2y^2}$$ so we have that $|z+a\bar{z}|=r$ can be written as
$$(1+a)^2x^2+(1-a)^2y^2=r^2$$
which is precisely the equation of an ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}=1$$ with
$$A^2=\frac{r^2}{(1+a)^2},\quad B^2=\frac{r^2}{(1-a)^2}$$